# ZBarCode reader some times showing wrong scanning data in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk

I am facing one little issue using ZBarCode reader in iPhone, i have implemented ZBarCode and it is working successfully, however some times it usually add an integer value 0 at the beginning after scanning bar code and due to this some times result are not coming accurately, please let me know if i am doing some thing wrong.

Comment: I didnt find such issue whenever i have use it.still you can ask same question in support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Bar Code and QR code scanning i have created full detailed tutorial and posted sample code. and it gives me every time perfect info.

[**How to use Barcode Scanner (BR and QR) in iPhone Tutorial (using ZBar)**](http://rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-use-barcode-scanner-br-and-qr-in.html)

Here is the core logic.

startScanning method body this way

```
- (IBAction)startScanning:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Scanning..");    
    resultTextView.text = @"Scanning..";

    ZBarReaderViewController *codeReader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    codeReader.readerDelegate=self;
    codeReader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = codeReader.scanner;
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 0];

    [self presentViewController:codeReader animated:YES completion:nil];    

}
```

Implement ZBar's Delegate method

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    //  get the decode results
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];

    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        // just grab the first barcode
        break;

    // showing the result on textview
    resultTextView.text = symbol.data;    

    resultImageView.image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // dismiss the controller 
    [reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post code you are using? Maybe you are using old referecne? Make sure all references are pointing nil value before parsing new scanned data.

Comment: ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [[ZBarReaderViewController alloc] init];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    reader.tracksSymbols = YES;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;
    
    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 1];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:reader animated:YES completion:nil];
    [reader release];